# How to chart multiple Y using html chart helper in Asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Hello all: I would like to have the option of charting two database fields together. Right now this charts just Cash for multiple years. I would like to also chart "OfficeSupplies" on the same graph. Does anyone know how to do that? I tried:
yValues: chartData, yFields: "Cash","OfficeSupplies"); 
... but that doesn't work. I'm getting the message: "named argument specifications must appear after all fixed arguments have been specified." Any ideas on charting multiple things at once?

Thanks,

Ruben

```
var chartData = db.FinancialPeriods.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM FinancialPeriods");

var myChart = new Chart(width: 600, height: 400)
              .AddTitle("Cash Chart")
              .AddSeries(
                  chartType: "Line",
                  //chartType: "Bubble",
                  //name: "Employee",
                  xValue: chartData, xField: "Year",
                  yValues: chartData, yFields: "Cash",
              );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this way

var myChart = new Chart(width: 600, height: 400)

```
          .AddTitle("Cash Chart")
          .AddSeries(
              chartType: "Line",
              //chartType: "Bubble",
              //name: "Employee",
              xValue: chartData, xField: "Year",
              yValues: chartData, yFields: "Cash",
          );

          .AddSeries(
              chartType: "Line",
              //chartType: "Bubble",
              //name: "Employee",
              xValue: chartData, xField: "Year",
              yValues: chartData, yFields: "OfficeSupplies",
          );
```